# What do fsolve in this machine learning task?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, python

I am reading this book Building Machine Learning Systems with Python and can not understand   what function "fsolve" do in eample.  In example I have test data data and I built the model. My model is **0.08844*x^2 - 97.31*x + 2.853e+04**. I need find what x when f(y) = 100000. I understand that need  find and use **inverse function**. But in book example they subtract 10000 from  model and after use **fsolve**. Why did the do it?
[image]

Comment: It looks like `fsolve` finds the root of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fsolve returns a value x, such that f(x) = 0.  In this case, it is desired to find a value x such that fbt2 = 100000.  Therefore, fbt2 - 100000 is used as the "f(x)" in fsolve, which therefore returns a value x such that fbt2 - 100000 = 0, which therefore solves fbt2 = 100000, as desired.